# How can I make two floated <divs> not overlap?

Tags: css, css-float, overlap

I'm designing a website that has banners that are floated left and right.  When I make the window very narrow, the banner on the right begins to cover the banner on the left.  How can I stop the banners from overlapping and simply stop moving once they hit each other?

Comment: Hi, could you show a live example / create a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to set a min-width on the containing element.  The min-width is the size of both floated elements widths.